# Adding Azure Bot Project to a Solution that already contains a Web Application

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I'm in the process of creating a chat bot for my project that will ultimately be integrated into Microsoft Teams. I've looked around and I haven't found much on this but I was just wondering if it possible or a good idea to add an Azure Bot service to an existing Solution that already contains a web application project.

Can this be done? If so, are there any downside to this approach?

Comment: Can you describe what your end-product is, in more detail? [Bots already integrate really well with Teams, directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Or are you thinking of having the bot in a Teams tab or something? If so, you could probably embed it with [Web Chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Comment: I have a solution that already contains a Web application project. I was wondering if including another project which contains the bot will cause any issues in the long run.

My Web application is also in .Net Framework 4.72 while the bot is in .net Core 2.1. This is causing me a lot of issues right now since I'm trying to use code shared by both of them. Is it possible to use a bot that is .Net Framework 4.7.2?

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer includes a response to your comment.

This is possible. You just need your bot to target .NET Framework v4.7.2. Just adjust your Startup and Config code. See [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_webapi).